# python set matrix add operation

Tags: python, set, addition

I have a input matrix looks like this

```
grid = [[1,1,2],[1,2,3],[3,2,4]]
```

I am using the following code to construct a matrix of sets.

```
m,n = len(grid), len(grid[0])
valuesets = [[set()]*n for _ in range(m)]

for j in range(n):
    s = sum(grid[0][:j+1])
    valuesets[0][j].add(s)
    print valuesets[0][0]
```

The output gives me

```
set([1])
set([1, 2])
set([1, 2, 4])
```

I am wondering why valuesets[0][0] is being updated each time in the for loop but not stays the same value set([1]) like I expected? Thanks.

Comment: Default Argument Values:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Comment: Don't do that `[set()]*n`. Use `[set() for _ in range(n)]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `[set()] * n` creates a list by copying the same `set()` instance.

If you want to get a list of distinct set objects, use `[set() for _ in range(n)] instead`.